# What's the best way to get the Directory of a URL using php?

Tags: php

Im trying to set active classes in a nav using php.  Now I need to set it by directory rather than complete URL as I have a main landing page for each directory with sub navigation for the other pages within the directory.  I was going to use the following but this returns the full url.

```
function curPageURL() {
$pageURL = 'http';
    if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
$pageURL .= "://";
    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
} else {
$pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
}

return $pageURL;}

 function activeLink($pageID) {
if ( $pageID == curPageURL() ) {
    echo 'class="active"';
} }
```

Then I call activeLink() in a nav item like this:

`<li class="projectchild padding1"><a href="http://www.strangeleaves.com/nexus/index.php" <?php activelink('http://www.strangeleaves.com/nexus/index.php'); ?> >nexus</a></li>`

Your suggestions on how to modify this to return the directory instead would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to extract the `directory name` from an `URL` you can use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) as:

```
$url = 'http://www.strangeleaves.com/nexus/index.php';
$arr = parse_url($url);
$path = dirname($arr['path']); // $path is now /nexus
```

Comment: This approach isn't as fool proof as one might think. `parse_url` can fail when `$url` isn't nicely formed.

Comment: You could cut out a line here by passing `PHP_URL_PATH` as a second parameter to `parse_url()`

Answer (score 0):

You could get the full URL and then explode it to get down to your directory, like so:

```
$currentFile = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
$parts = Explode('/', $currentFile);
$thisDir = $parts[count($parts) - 2];
```